# How to specify environment variables in loopback 4?

Tags: loopbackjs

I found documentation for the previous version https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Environment-specific-configuration.html but I can't find a documentation for the version 4

There's something I'm missing or v4 doesn't yet support environment specific configuration?

Comment: Even I couldn't find how to specify configuration in loopback 4. I was trying to configure a common base path for all the APIs.

Comment: hey dude, I put my `dotenv` configuration in `index.js` (next to the `package.json`) and it worked !!! If you want similar solution try...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After breaking my head looking for documentation - these are the steps I used to handle environment configuration:

1. Step 1: Install dotenv package

   `npm install --s dotenv`
2. Add a `.env` file to the root of your project (server/.env). Sample format in this file given below:

   `SampleKey=testValue`
3. Require this file from the index.js file (I placed this on line 2)

   `// Addition of dotenv for access to process.env (environment variables)
   const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();`
4. You should be able to access keys from your file now as follows:

   `console.log(process.env.SampleKey);`

Answer (score 4):

Loopback 4 doesn't support environment specific configurations yet. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377667/3904327

You can follow this github issue for the same.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1464

Comment: I'm asking in that issue as well (I'm Edo78 on github)