# Loopback 4 test configurations are not picked up

Tags: loopback

I followed [Loopback4 datasources](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/DataSources.html) documentation and placed **sample.datasource.json** and **sample.test.datasource.json** files under **src/datasources**. Whenever I run `npm run test` my repository is injected with original datasource but not the test datasource.

My datasource configuration file sample.datasource.json is

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "connector": "postgresql",
  "url": "postgres://postgres:user@localhost:5432/somedb",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "user": "postgres",
  "password": "****",
  "database": "somedb"
}
```

and my test configuration file sample.test.datasource.json is

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "connector": "memory",
  "localStorage": "sample-test",
  "debug": true
}
```

Here is my repository file **sample.repository.ts** placed under src/repositories.

```
export class SampleRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<SomeModel,string> {
  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.sample') dataSource: SomeDataSource,
  ) {
    super(SomeModel, dataSource);
  }
}
```

I exported `NODE_ENV` to "test" and tried to run `npm run test`.

Comment: What solution did you implement for configuring different environment, since loopback 4 doesn't yet include environment configurations?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am manually creating instance of juggler.DataSource and passing it as argument in repository constructor for Test environments.

Answer (score 5):

*Hello from the LoopBack team :)*

LoopBack 4 does not support environment specific configuration yet. We are discussing this feature in the GitHub [issue #1464](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1464), there is also a discussion about modifying datasource configuration specifically for tests - see [issue #1396](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1396).

There are workaround possible, see the following resources for inspiration:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Deploying-to-IBM-Cloud.html#updating-application
- https://itnext.io/loopback-4-database-configuration-8f085399268